# using progress or meter tag with reactive value

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

In my vue class based component i want to use a reactive value to display changes of progress in realtime using a `<progress>` or `<meter>` tag.

For this i created a variable the houses a base value

```
percentCore: number = 0
```

Then my plan was to listen to changes to this variable whenever i update it from a password checker function with a get/set (which is the recommended computed prop way for vue class based components)

```
  get percent(): number {
    return this.percentCore
  }

  set percent(val) {
    this.percentCore = val
  }
```

Now i assign the reactive percent variable to the "value" attribute of the progress tag

```
 <progress max="100" value="percent"></progress>
```

But nothing happens when i update, however the passwordChecker function works totally fine, since i can see the correct value to be updated when i print

```
 {{ percent }}
```

My conclusion is that the value of progress or meter tags isnt allowed to be reactive. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to set the "value" attribute using `v-bind:` (or the shorthand `:`), as in:

```html
<progress max="100" :value="percent"></progress>
```

Omitting the `:` would set the attribute to the string `"percent"`, rather than the value of the `percent` property.